# Logbook logging actuator health calls even when excluded

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, logbook

I am using Zolando Logbook for Spring Boot services (Version 2.1.6 spring boot version, 1.13.0 Logbook version) and the actuator health endpoint gets logged even though it is specified as excluded. Other endpoints are excluded correctly when included in yaml file.

This is the relevant section of the yaml file:

```
logbook:
  exclude:
    - /actuator/health
    - /actuator/**
    - /health
    - /v2/api-docs
    - /swagger-ui.html
```

Comment: Can you remove     - /actuator/health
from the exclude because /actuator/** matches all the actuator+suffix endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,
I tried as following and it worked:

```
logbook:
  exclude[1]: '**/swagger-ui.html'
  exclude[0]: '**/v2/api-docs'
  exclude[3]: '**/swagger-resources/**'
  exclude[2]: '**/webjars/**'
  exclude[5]: '**/'
  exclude[4]: '**/csrf'
```

In case you have .properties file :

```
logbook.exclude[0]=**/v2/api-docs
logbook.exclude[1]=**/swagger-ui.html
logbook.exclude[2]=**/webjars/**
logbook.exclude[3]=**/swagger-resources/**
logbook.exclude[4]=**/csrf
logbook.exclude[5]=**/
```

In case you have to exclude more paths, You may define as :

```
logbook.write.max-body-size=10
```

I took the solution from [here](https://github.com/zalando/logbook/issues/445#issuecomment-680245900)

Comment: No need for that. If you read the linked site, this is only needed for properties because you do not have any other possibility to declare an array.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem so I would like to share my solution for anyone in same situation who is trying to make logbook work with log4j2 in spring boot

Make sure you have correct dependencies in **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${logbook.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Configure log4j by creating **log4j2.xml** file in  *src/main/resources*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console_Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="logbook-logToFile" fileName="logs/logbook.log"
            filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/app-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="19500KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.zalando.logbook.Logbook" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console_Appender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="logbook-logToFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console_Appender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="logbook-logToFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This configuration outputs everything into console as well as into specified file.(You can also use yaml, json or programmatical configurations described in here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html )

To configure logbook (for example exclude some endpoints from logging) just create a configuration class like this one:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.zalando.logbook.Logbook;
import static org.zalando.logbook.Conditions.exclude;
import static org.zalando.logbook.Conditions.requestTo;

@Configuration
public class LogbookConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Logbook logbook() {
        Logbook logbook = Logbook.builder()
            .condition(exclude(
                requestTo("/actuator/**"),
                requestTo("/admin/**")))
            .build();
        return logbook;
    }

}
```

(I had hard time finding these static imports since my IDE wont suggest anything here)

This is just basic setup, you can find more in depth informations in logbook documentation: https://github.com/zalando/logbook#conditional

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using quotes could help you to use wildcards. I also miss some further documentation for using Logbook Spring starter. However, this configuration works for me:

```
logbook:
  exclude:
    - "/swagger-ui/**"
    - "/actuator/**"
    - "/v2/api-docs"
    - "/swagger-resources/**"
    - "/favicon.ico"
```